# Changing version number for Android APK between Alpha, Beta, and Production versions

Tags: android, google-play, versioning

When using the alpha and beta testing feature of Google Play, I use the following format for specifying a version number:

```
Alpha Version: 2.1.1-a1 (200100101)
Beta Version: 2.1.1-b1 (200100110)
Production Version: 2.1.1 (200100199)
```

The alpha version is released first. If there are no issues, I upload a new APK with an incremented version number for beta. If the beta passes testing with no issues, then I upload another APK with an incremented number for production. If an alpha or beta version had issues, I would fix them and upload a new alpha or beta version with a version number something like "2.1.1-a2" meaning the second alpha.

There seems to be a better way to do this by using the "promote to beta" or "promote to production" feature. The problem here is if an alpha is labeled as "2.1.1-a1" and it gets moved to beta, it really needs to be called "2.1.1-b1". This would require a new APK to be built which means I can't currently use the "move to x" feature.

How can I change the version number to reflect what stage it is in after promotion (be it alpha, beta, or production)?`

Comment: I have the exact same problem, I use an A prefix for Alpha, a B prefix for Beta and no prefix for production.  Therefore, I am also unable to use the 'promote to' feature.  I don't think there's any way around it though as a manifest change with the new version will always mean a new APK.  Even without using prefixes, I'm still not sure about it as it could mean (depending of the number of Alpha and Beta versions you did), going live with say, 'Version 1.4' which seems a little odd.  How did you proceed?

Comment: I still just upload a new APK with a different version value. Usually I don't need to have too many subsequent alphas for a specific version, so it's not too bad.

Comment: Cool, pretty much what I'm doing too.

Comment: I think this is a better way than using "promote to beta" or "move to production" feature because if the version number doesn't increment, your beta users won't get the update to the production version which might be the same as your beta if there were no bugs but they won't be able to rate the app. There should be a way of notifying alpha users of a new beta and beta users of a new production version.

Comment: For anyone concerned: I've just been using the beta distribution system from Crashlytics.